# Why can't BIOS be accessed in 64bit mode on Intel/AMD chips?

Tags: ms-dos, bios

I was interested in a possible rewrite of dos to dos 64bit. In my research I found several references that state all current motherboard BIOS interrupts are not accessible from 64bit Long or 64bit protected mode. Also, interrupts (ISR's) can not normally be entered by a debugger so reverse engineering is not practical. [OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page)  [Alt OS](http://aodfaq.wikidot.com/)

Most BIOS calls can be made if the processor is dropped back into 16bit Real Mode. But this is very slow.

1) Why can't BIOS calls be made from 64bit Intel/AMD modes? Isn't 32 bit compatible with 16bit, and 64bit compatible with 16 & 32 - each instruction set being a super-set of the earlier design?

2) It appears a simple 64bit rewrite of the BIOS is not possible otherwise someone would have done it. What is keeping a 64bit mode DOS compatible BIOS from being written and distributed?

Comment: In related news, there’s now a 64-bit DOS extender, [DX64](https://www.bttr-software.de/forum/forum_entry.php?id=15853).

Comment: There's also a [32-bit MS-DOS](http://www.pdos.org/), sort of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The BIOS code and interface were developed on a processor that only had 16-bit real mode addressing, which means it is not compatible with other addressing modes and code will run only if CPU is in a mode that is compatible with real mode so on later CPUs it could be also in virtual 8086 mode. The addressing modes and default operand lengths differ in other modes. And on the other hand, BIOS is just a way to boot your OS, and when your OS is running, it is expected to either fall back to compatible mode if it needs to access BIOS routines, or just have its own drivers for peripherals that BIOS calls are not needed at all. Modern UEFI system runs in 32-bit mode. And BIOSes themselves can run in 32-bit mode during startup on newer machines to initialize CPU and system components like PCI devices.

Comment: Concur with 'just a way to boot your OS' in any modern system.  Once running, the OS can and should implement its own services independently of the BIOS.

Comment: The system firmware is still used when the system’s running, but the interfaces are very different compared to the old days of interrupt services — think ACPI for example.

Comment: Minor correction: 32 and 64 bit (U)EFI exists. UEFI can only run a bootloader of the same mode. Worse than BIOS, it is extremely complicated to interface with UEFI across different modes and no major OS does this. Therefore, to boot 64 bit Windows in UEFI mode, the firmware must also be 64 bit. (This was a issue with MacOS as early models with 32-bit EFI cannot run the 64 bit kernel, and were dropped in 10.8)

Answer (score 5):

### The key word is "modes"

A 64-bit x86 processor can be switched into 16, 32 and 64-bit modes (which is an over-simplification, there are more than that), but code written for one mode won't run correctly in a different mode.

The reasons for this are many and varied, but the main issue is that the instructions in the code mean slightly different things in the different modes. To answer the obvious question, yes, it would be possible in theory to devise a computer architecture where 64-bit code could make calls to 16-bit code, and have things work correctly. However, the x86 tribe of processors (they are too varied to be just one family) were not designed on that basis: if it occurred to anyone, it clearly wasn't considered important enough to be worth providing. No, they can't be changed to provide it without making them incompatible with the existing processors.

I do know of one family of computers that were designed that way, the Data General Nova/Eclipse/Eclipse MV series. Those grew from 16-bit to 32-bit, but Data General didn't try to take the idea further, and no longer exists.

### Good reasons why nobody has written a 64-bit DOS-compatible BIOS

There is no 64-bit MS-DOS to make it useful. It would not be useful with more sophisticated 64-bit operating systems, like Linux or Windows 7/8.1/10, because they need more sophisticated interfaces to hardware to run with decent speed and reliability. Those operating systems only use the BIOS during their early boot phases, and take over direct control of hardware thereafter.

A BIOS is somewhat hardware-specific. A universal one, for any 64-bit x86 motherboard, is almost certainly impractical. Anyone writing one would have to produce variations for different motherboards and/or chipsets. It sounds like a lot of work, for little gain.

A 64-bit MS-DOS would be of little use without applications to run on it. There aren't any, and there's no point in writing any without an OS to run them on. Even if it existed, you can't re-write existing DOS software for it without breaching copyright (and a great deal of work), and it seems very unlikely that any software vendor would produce anything for it. Almost all of the free software being produced and maintained needs a more sophisticated OS to run.

What you're proposing is not really a retrocomputing project, but the creation of a new operating system, which looks and behaves like an old one, but is much less useful, as well as being a lot of work. Nobody will stop you doing this, but not many people are likely to join you either.

Comment: I know you know this, but for the OP’s benefit, the key part of the first point is indeed the mode, and not its size. This is really a variant of the old protected mode on DOS problems which led to the creation of 16- and 32-bit DOS extenders (and IBM’s ABIOS, for OS/2).

Comment: So... Your saying the problem is memory addressing and not instruction set? I thought the 16bit BIOS could be accessed from 32bit mode?

Comment: The BIOS is there, but BIOS code is 16-bit real mode code and thus needs to be executed as such. If CPU is in 32-bit protected mode, it cannot execute 16-bit real mode code properly because a lot of things are different. The default memory operand sizes are different, and pointers are different, segment registers are pmode selectors.

Comment: @jwzumwalt, to simplify things a bit, an x86-64 CPU has two operating modes: 16/32-bit mode, and 32/64-bit mode.  In 16/32 mode, the 16-bit BIOS can be accessed from 32-bit code, but you can't run 64-bit code.  In 32/64 mode, you can run 64-bit code, but the 16-bit BIOS is inaccessible.